# microsoft graph get access token that can be use to get user's calender

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, access-token, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-calendar

My main purpose is to get User's calender by single admin access token.
i am trying to get access token  by following these steps.

**URL** :[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenentId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenentId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)
**Body**
client_id:client_ID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_secret:client_secretID
grant_type:client_credentials

this give me an access token but when i try to use this token to get the users data from this url
**https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users**
i got this error

{
"error": {
"code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
"message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2021-04-20T11:13:13",
"request-id": "66d3af76-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c39e7xxxxxx",
"client-request-id": "66d3af76-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c39exxxxxx"
}
}
}
}

i have enabled all the permission required in my Azure app

Comment: Have you added Application permissions User.Read.All? You can parse the access token at https://jwt.ms and see if your `roles` claim has this permission.

Comment: yes.i have provided the premission but i cant see them in my JWT access token when i decode it ..
what i assume is . i am making mistake 
in grant_type or scope 
am i giving the right values.?

Comment: Scope is good, just do as I said in Answer box. If my posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: yes i think its works.
thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are using the App Context flow where you would be getting App token. Here you need to specify the Application permissions 'User.Read.All' in Azure AD App to work. Make sure you have granted admin consent for this permission. Then you would see that permission in the token and it allows you to get users from `/users`.

[image]

If you don't see the above grant admin consent button then you are not the global admin so you should as your admin to grant consent to this permission.